# A lot of same offline devices in device chooser

Tags: android

I have a phone connect problem as the picture

There are a lot of the same phones in Android chooser and there are offline, I cannot debug it.

The problem happen in the NB.

OS is Windows7 64bit

Eclipse is Version: 3.7.2  64Bit

Android SDK r16

Phone HTC desire S

JDK jdk1.7.0_03 64Bit

But the same phone use successfully in my Vista NB and Win7 32Bit PC.

Comment: what is your specific problem?  You are unable to choose your phone in the IDE as a deployment target?

Comment: I have this same problem with my Samsung Infuse from AT&T.

Answer (score 1):

Try using eclipse 3.5.  That is what is recommended.